# Chern-Simons theory for FQHE

Tags: quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

Recently I have read something about describing FQHE within chern simons field theories. According to Atland's text book,Condensed matter field theory, one can map interacting fermions to composite fermions with chern simons gauge field(statistical field). Follow the text book, we start with partition function and introduce statistical field to obtain effective action.
$$Z = N \int D(\psi,\bar\psi)Da\hspace{0.3 cm}\exp\left(iS_{CF}[\psi,\bar\psi,a]+i\frac{\theta}{4}S_{CS}[a]\right)$$
$$S_{CF}[\psi ,\bar\psi,a] = \int d^{3}x \bar\psi\left(i\partial_{0}
+\mu - \phi +\frac{1}{2m}(-i\partial_{x}+A_{ext}-a)^{2}-V\right)\psi 
+ S_{int}[\psi,\bar\psi]$$

For detailed notation, one can refer Altland A., Simons B.D. - Condensed Matter Field Theory-CUP (2010) 2ED P.575.
I am wondering why above action $S_{CF}$ can represent equivalent IQHE state.Because there is interacting part $S_{int}$ in $S_{CF}$, it doesn't make sense if $S_{CF}$ describes IQHE.  Thanks!